# How to force Bootstrap toggle-menu to open over another div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I force the Bootstrap toggle-menu to open over a div as seen below?
When I click the globe glyphicon the menu opens right beside the globe.
At this point the width seems not right set for the href link because
when I move over a link just a small part of the full with becomes grey in background.

This is my bootply [Demo](http://www.bootply.com/ZisW8W7Nnf)

I am looking for two solutions.
Number 1:
[image]

Number 2:
[image]

Comment: Please include the rest of your code, or better yet, create a [**bootply**](http://www.bootply.com/new)

Comment: Thanks for your hint with bootply. I added a demo above.

Answer (score 2):

After spending hours in the jungle of bootstrap code I found out
that I had just to add the following piece of css to get my wanted solution number two.
I am still wondering how to display the toggle-menu right over the banner
like I have visualized for my first wanted solution...

Here is solution number two solved:

```
#menu .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 55px;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
            box-shadow: none;
}
#menu .open .dropdown-menu > li > a,
#menu .open .dropdown-menu .dropdown-header {
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
}
#menu .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
    line-height: 20px;
}
```

You can also view the result on bootply [here](http://www.bootply.com/HTOkYDjdjo)